# Where messages are stored in SignalR

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr

I'm new to SignalR, but I've read and done some of SignalR tutorials. I wonder where messages are stored in SignalR. If I integrate some authentications and build a chat app, where messages are stored? If I need a SQL database, how can I design it to save users' conversations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your messages are going to store in database if you have connected your app to a database. If not then it's going to be temp save in a local server which could be your machine and will lose the data when you reboot it.

Once you've installed the SQL database you can save the messages in it.

For Eg:

```
 $('#btnSendMsg').click(function () {
   var msg = $("#textMessage").val();

   if (msg.length > 0) {

       var UserName = $('#UserName').val();
        objHub.server.saveMessagetoDB(UserName, msg);
```

Comment: That means I can save 1 conversation to 1 database table?

Comment: Well that depends on your approach, like if you wish you can store 1 conversation to 1 table or if you want you can store multiple conversation to a single table.